# TypeScript: Cannot reference public things in static member

Tags: typescript

I am trying to call a public member function from a static variable this so typescript:

```js
class myClass {
    static myTmp: myClass;

    constructor(elem: HTMLElement) {
        elem.addEventListener(“mousedown”, this.callThis);
    }
    public setTmp() {
        myClass.myTmp = this;
    }
    public callThis() {
        myClass.myTmp.myMethod();
    }
    public myMethod() {
        console.log("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

But I keep getting `myClass.myTmp.myMethod is not a function`.
This example may seem weird, but it makes sense in my real problem. I have tried doing it through a global variable as well, but still no luck. I would like to keep it all within one class. Am I missing something major here?

EDIT:
This is what I was trying to do, and this works:

```js
class myClass {
    static myTmp?: myClass;

    constructor(elem: HTMLElement) {
        elem.addEventListener(“mousedown”, this.callThis.bind(this));
    }
    public setTmp() {
        myClass.myTmp = this;
    }
    public callThis() {
        myClass.myTmp?.myMethod();
    }
    public myMethod() {
        console.log("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I then have a list of myClass'es and at some point "setTmp" is called, enabling the "myMethod" method.

Comment: It worked for me in the TS playground as expected.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it is because I am doing it from within an event?

Comment: Updated it to be closer to the actual problem

Comment: `elem.addEventListener('mousedown', () => this.callThis())`

Comment: `this` in the event handler is the element and not the object. You can store `this` to a variable first and then use it. Eg: `var self = this;`

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I solved it by using `elem.addEventListener("mousedown", this.callThis.bind(this));` instead.

Comment: please don't edit the question during the process otherwise it becomes hard understanding what was the initial requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you simply use arrow functions?

`elem.addEventListener('mousedown', () => this.callThis());`

changing it to this code will work. You don't need to be using the `.bind` at all :)